# Time complexity of hash table, separate chaining (average case)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, hashtable

For a hash-table with separate chaining, the average case runtime complexity for insertion is `O(n/m + 1)` where `n/m` is the load factor and `+ 1` is for the hash function.

Could this be considered equivalent to `O(n/m)` under big-O notation since `1` is just a constant, and any multiple of `n/m` can bound `n/m + 1`?

Comment: Big-O only really cares about the term that grows fastest. For example, if your time complexity is `5n^3 + 1000n^2 + 20n + 1`, it would be considered `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @paddy yeah, so would I be correct in saying `O(n/m) == O(n/m + 1)`? It's a non-practical question in semantics, I know, but I'm unfortunately vying for an academic grade here. Theoretically you can bound the load factor to `[0, 1]`, so not sure if that matters when ignoring `+ 1` for the average case.

Comment: If `n/m` tends to a value larger than 1, then it's `O(n/m)`. If it tends to a value smaller than 1, you would probably consider it `O(1)`. Who knows what your professor expects? Maybe you should approach them and/or review your learning materials to determine what's expected. Using Stack Overflow to vet your homework is risky, because most people here are in industry, and sometimes pure academic or beginner stuff uses bogus criteria that's not actually important in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the average case runtime complexity for insertion is O(n/m + 1)

I normally simplify and remove lower-order components when expressing complexity in big-O notation, rather than having things in there that are yet to be simplified.  I'd suggest you say "the number of operations" is n/m + 1 (or +2 perhaps, if the insertion itself can be considered an operation), then consider how to express a simplified big-O complexity, as you're indeed doing with this question:

> Could this be considered equivalent to O(n/m) under big-O notation since 1 is just a constant, and any multiple of n/m can bound n/m + 1?

The +1 is indeed superfluous.  Your reasoning is correct.  Another way of explaining it that might or might not help: no matter how slow it is to hash, if you were doing operations with even O(log(log(K)) complexity for some variable K, that K-related value would - as K increases - eventually grow large enough that the +1 would be irrelevant.

The more interesting question is whether it's meaningful to write O(n/m), or should you be simplifying to O(n) or O(1)?  To answer that, let's think of n/m as the load factor: if we keep doing insertions, how will our load factor keep changing?  There are two possibilities:

- if we aren't actively doing something to keep the load factor in a particular range, then it will grow linearly with insertions; if we're not varying the bucket count at all, then the m factor is constant and hence the complexity simplifies to O(n)
- if we are growing the hash table as we go, then while we don't have
  to, why *wouldn't* we keep it in some linear proportion to n (i.e.
  keeping the load factor beneath some fixed value), such
  that the insertion complexity is O(1)?  [That's the obvious
  thing to do, and what every implementation I've ever seen that can
  resize actually does do.]

So, the most-simplified (and therefore correct) expressions of the big-O complexity of further insertions is either O(1) (for resizing hash tables), or O(N) for fixed-bucket-count tables with load factors much greater than 1.